# What's the easiest way to aggregate my CSV data in Python 3.9?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, aggregate

I'm using Python 3.9.  I'm trying to parse this CSV file that has 3 columns of data

```
55,Fake ISD,SUCCESS
56,Other ISD,None
57,Third ISD,WARNING
58,Fourth ISD,FAILURE
59,Main ISD,SUCCESS
60,Secondary ISD,SUCCESS
```

I was wondering if there is some out-of-the-box library that would parse the CSV to aggregate the data based on results of the third column.  That is, I woudl want a report taht lists

```
SUCCESS - 3 entries - Fake ISD, Main ISD, Secondary ISD
WARNING - 1 entry - Third ISD
FAILURE - 1 entry - Fourth ISD
None - 1 entry - Other ISD
```

How would I aggregate these in Python 3.9?

Comment: It is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) to ask for library suggestions here. Your question could be on-topic if yo rephrased it to show your attempt at achieving this and asked a specific question about the implementation, instead of asking for a recommendation for a library. Please read [ask] and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), and provide a [mre] showing your specific problem.

Comment: The common-sense approach would be to use Pandas. Specifically, look into [DataFrame.groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). You will find lots of learning material for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `pandas`:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("your_file.csv", header=None)

x = df.groupby(2)[1].agg(list)
for i, d in zip(x.index, x):
    print(f'{i} - {len(d)} - {", ".join(d)}')
```

Prints:

```
FAILURE - 1 - Fourth ISD
None - 1 - Other ISD
SUCCESS - 3 - Fake ISD, Main ISD, Secondary ISD
WARNING - 1 - Third ISD
```